Flutter Alarm Manager library fails to build after updating to Flutter 3.24.5
I updated the Flutter and Dart versions, and now my project fails to build, displaying the following error:
import io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView;
                      ^
  symbol:   class FlutterNativeView
  location: package io.flutter.view
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I use: android_alarm_manager_plus: ^4.0.4
I attempted to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 8.3.0, but the issue still persists. Has anyone else encountered this?
